# Distribution of independent events with equal probability

Tags: statistics

Sorry this was a wrong question posted!

Comment: I dont think SO is best place for ask this question, so I flag it to migrate to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/) but I dont find math in suggested destinations.

Comment: Try to post this question on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the per-customer probability `p` of purchasing gives you no information about how many people will show up.  However, if you know that `N` people showed up and purchase decisions are independent, the distribution of how many will make a purchase is [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters `N` and `p`.